# React: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

here is the error msg from console:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Code\django\DRF-REACT\node_modules\prop-types\node_modules\react-is\index.js'
at Object.../node_modules/prop-types/node_modules/react-is/index.js (has.js:1:1)

```
at Object.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at Object.../node_modules/prop-types/index.js (index.js:9:1)
at Object.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at Module.../node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/AppBar/AppBar.js (log.js:59:1)
at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

The problem is >react-is is outside of prop-types/node_modules and prop-types/node-modules is an empty folder. I tried to move the react-is into the node modules folder in Vscode but it cannot be done.

Answer (score 3):

Following steps resolved the issue in my react application

1. Closed VS studio
2. Run the following commands

   ```
   npm update 
   npm audit fix
   npm start
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You might have some complications with your `node_modules` folder and installing `react-is`.

A couple ideas:

1. `npm install react-is` : make sure the package is installed instead of physically moving it.
2. `rm -rf node_modules` :  delete `node_modules` folder and do a fresh `npm install`

One or both of these could help if you haven't done them already.

Comment: I tried both and react-is is now in the right place.  Now I'm getting invalid hook call errors probably because I have 2 copies of node_modules, one at app level and one at the project level. I'm following a youtube tutorial and I can see the tutorial has the same folder structure. Don't why mine is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Simply closing VS Studio and running npm start solved the problem for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34478387)

Answer (score 0):

I only used another (port) and restart my application using command(npm start).
after that the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

close the vs code, close the application and restart both, it works properly.. :)
Goes the error...!

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete node_modules
2. Delete package.lock.json
3. run `npm clean cache`
4. run `npm i`
5. Then run `npm start`